# SSRS report: Could not update a list of fields for the query. An item with same key has already been added

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have written a stored procedure as follows:

```
ALTER       PROCEDURE [dbo].[Transaction] 
    (
    @date_start date,
    @date_end date
    )
AS
BEGIN


with 
rntexportbatch as (
Select 
                fb.BatchId,
                rt.TransactionId,
                count(*) as line_Count
from            CxWarehouse.dbo.FinancialBatchPostingDetail fbpd
INNER JOIN      CxWarehouse.dbo.FinancialBatchPosting fb 
on              (fb.BatchPostingId = fbpd.BatchPostingId and NominalAccount='12000' )  ---and NominalAccount='12000'
INNER JOIN      CxWarehouse.dbo.FinancialBatch finb 
on              (finb.BatchId = fb.BatchId)
INNER JOIN      CxWarehouse.dbo.SystemLookup l 
on              (l.LookupReference = finb.TransactionTypeId and LookupTypeId = 42)
INNER JOIN      CxWarehouse.dbo.Financialtransaction ft 
on              (ft.TransactionId = fbpd.TransactionId)
LEFT JOIN       CxWarehouse.dbo.RentTransactionElement rte 
on              (rte.TransactionElementId = ft.EntityId)
LEFT JOIN       CxWarehouse.dbo.RentElement re 
ON              (re.ElementId = rte.ElementId)
LEFT JOIN       CxWarehouse.dbo.RentTransaction rt 
ON              (rt.TransactionId = rte.TransactionId)
Group by rt.TransactionId,fb.BatchId

)


Select
                ast.AssetId,
                ast.AssetReference,
                ast.[Agreement Description],
                ast.CompanyIds,
                rntAcc.AccountId,
                rntAcc.AccountReference,
                rntAcc.PaymentReference,
                rt.TransactionId, 
                rt.AccountId, 
                rt.TransactionDate,
                rt.TransactionTypeId,
                [Transaction Type Id Description],
                rt.PostingDate,
                rt.PeriodNumber,
                rt.Description as 'Rent Transaction Description',               
                rt.Notes,
                [ElementId Description] ,
                rntPay.BatchReference as 'Import BatchId',
                rntPay.[Import Value],
                rntexportbatch.BatchId as 'Export BatchId',
                final.Value as 'Export Value'
from            CxWarehouse.dbo.RentTransaction as rt


LEFT Join (
                Select          LookupId,
                                LookupTypeId,
                                LookupReference,
                                Description as 'Transaction Type Id Description'
                from            CxWarehouse.dbo.SystemLookup
                where           LookupTypeId = 46
        ) lu
on              rt.TransactionTypeId = lu.LookupReference
LEFT Join (
                Select          
                            te.TransactionId,
                            te.TransactionElementId,
                            te.ElementId, 
                            te.Value,
                            rntElm.Description as 'ElementId Description' 
                from        CxWarehouse.dbo.RentTransactionElement as te
                
                LEFT Join (
                                    Select * from CxWarehouse.dbo.RentElement
                            ) rntElm
                on te.ElementId = rntElm.ElementId
                
            ) final 
on      rt.TransactionId = final.TransactionId

LEFT JOIN (
                Select          
                            t.AccountId,
                            t.AccountReference,
                            t.PaymentReference, 
                            typ.Description as 'AccountType Description' 
                from        CxWarehouse.dbo.RentAccount as t
                left Join   CxWarehouse.dbo.RentAccountType as typ 
                on          t.AccountTypeId = typ.AccountTypeId
        ) rntAcc 

on      rt.AccountId = rntAcc.AccountId

Left Join (

                Select          
                            ast.AssetId,
                            AssetReference,
                            rntInf.AccountId,
                            rntInf.[Agreement Description],
                            rntInf.CompanyIds
                from        CxWarehouse.dbo.Asset as ast

                left join (
                                Select          
                                        rntAgAs.AgreementAssetId,
                                        rntAgAs.AgreementId,
                                        rntAgAs.AssetId,
                                        rntAgr.AccountId,
                                        rntAgr.[Agreement Description],
                                        rntAgr.CompanyIds
                                from    CxWarehouse.dbo.RentAgreementAsset as rntAgAs
                                left join (

                                                Select          
                                                        rntAgmt.AgreementId,
                                                        rntAgmt.AgreementReference,
                                                        rntAgmt.AgreementTypeId,
                                                        rntAgmtTyp.Description as 'Agreement Description', 
                                                        rntAgmtTyp.CompanyIds,
                                                        accEpi.AccountId 
                                                from    CxWarehouse.dbo.RentAgreement as rntAgmt
                                                LEFT JOIN   CxWarehouse.dbo.RentAgreementType rntAgmtTyp
                                                on      rntAgmt.AgreementTypeId = rntAgmtTyp.AgreementTypeId
                                                Left Join (
                                                            Select 
                                                                    rntAgEp.AgreementEpisodeId,
                                                                    rntAgEp.AgreementId,
                                                                    rntAgAc.AccountId 
                                                            from    CxWarehouse.dbo.RentAgreementEpisode as rntAgEp
                                                            Left Join   CxWarehouse.dbo.RentAgreementAccount as rntAgAc
                                                            on          rntAgEp.AgreementEpisodeId =rntAgAc.AgreementEpisodeId 
                                                            ) accEpi
                                                on      rntAgmt.AgreementId = accEpi.AgreementId 
                                            ) rntAgr
                                on              rntAgAs.AgreementId = rntAgr.AgreementId 
                            ) rntInf
                    on              ast.AssetId = rntInf.AssetId
) ast 
on          rntAcc.AccountId = ast.AccountId

Left Join (

                Select          
                            rp.PaymentId,
                            rp.BatchReference,
                            rpd.PaymentDetailId, 
                            rpd.Value as 'Import Value',
                            GeneratedTransactionId 
                from        CxWarehouse.dbo.RentPayment as rp
                left Join   CxWarehouse.dbo.RentPaymentDetail rpd
                on          rp.PaymentId = rpd.PaymentId
                left join   CxWarehouse.dbo.RentPaymentPosting rpp
                on          rpd.PaymentDetailId = rpp.PaymentDetailId
                
) rntPay
on          rt.TransactionId = rntPay.GeneratedTransactionId
LEFT JOIN   rntexportbatch
on          rntexportbatch.TransactionId = rt.TransactionId

where       rt.PostingDate between @date_start  and @date_end 

END
```

I used that stored procedure in SSRS report. When I clicked on the dataset option of the report and refresh the data set, it gave following error:

[image]

I looked at the forum and found that error comes due to two or more columns have same name. I looked at the code and made sure that no column have same name. However, the problem still exist. Could anyone help me where I am making the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two columns both called `AccountID` being returned from your query

```
...
rntAcc.AccountId,
rntAcc.AccountReference,
rntAcc.PaymentReference,
rt.TransactionId, 
rt.AccountId, 
....
```

Alias or remove one of these columns.

Comment: Simple & Perfect!